# Another interesting question on Multinomial;

Tags: binomial-theorem

[image]

I don't know how to proceed with this problem... 
But as this question was given in chapter of binomial so maybe Binomial theorem comes into usuage.

UPDATE 1: I think this question deserves bounty..As nobody will answer ,waiting for 1 more day.

Comment: Is the first term $a_0 a_{2n}$ or $a_0 a_{2r}$ ?

Comment: Former one @Compulsive Masthurbator.

Comment: Well if its any help, looks like the sum is $a_n$ for $r=0$

Comment: If you will type it out legibly and clearly stated I am sure you will get answered. It is clearly elementary but I can't be sure what is written or asked. If you go to Help, choose Help Center, and under Our Model, choose How Do I Format Mathematics Here, read that, and click on the Quick Tutorial.